# Convert CASE to IIF for an Access query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, case, iif

I can not seem to find how to convert the below query that is written in T-SQL into an access query to be used in vba. I've read that using IIF instead of CASE (since case isn't supported by Access' SQL), but tried many different ways and cannot get it to work.

```
sSQL = "SELECT ba.BusinessEntityID,ba.AddressID
          ,(CASE WHEN ba.BusinessEntityID > 5
            THEN
            (SELECT pp.FirstName FROM [Person].[Person] pp
            WHERE pp.BusinessEntityID = ba.BusinessEntityID)
           Else 'AA' END) AS 'TEST'
    FROM Person.BusinessEntityAddress ba
    INNER JOIN person.AddressType at ON at.AddressTypeID = ba.AddressTypeID
    WHERE ba.BusinessEntityID < 11;"`
```

I get the error message as follows when trying to run the query above..

> Run-Time Error 3075 Syntax Error (missing operator) in query
>   expression '(CASE WHEN ba.BusinessEntityID > 5 THEN (SELECT
>   pp.FirstName FROM [Person].[Person] pp WHERE pp.BusinessEntityID =
>   ba.BusinessEntityID) Else 'AA' END) AS 'TEST'

Comment: Access will not accept `FROM [Person].[Person]`,  `FROM Person.BusinessEntityAddress` or `FROM person.AddressType`.  Use only the table names as they appear in Access --- do not qualify the table names with a schema or database name.

Comment: I'm doing this via SQL Server Native Client 11.0.. I used "Set db = OpenDatabase("AdventureWorks", False, False, sConnStr)". I've also tried changing them to `FROM [Person]![Person], FROM [Person]![BusinessEntityAddress], and FROM [Person]![AddressType]`

Comment: Does this simple query work in the same context as the query you're trying to fix?  `SELECT ba.*  FROM Person.BusinessEntityAddress ba`

Comment: Hmmmmmm, it doesn't work... I get the error "Run-Time 3024 Could not find file 'C:\Users\.....' But `SELECT * FROM [BusinessEntityAddress]` does work

Comment: You have more than one problem with that query.  Suggest you ignore `CASE WHEN` until after you have the rest of the query working correctly.  Does Access accept this without complaints?  `SELECT ba.BusinessEntityID, ba.AddressID FROM BusinessEntityAddress ba INNER JOIN AddressType at ON at.AddressTypeID = ba.AddressTypeID WHERE ba.BusinessEntityID < 11;`

Answer (score 0):

IIF syntax :

```
IIF(condition, if_true_part, if_false_part)
```

Also, you cannot make pseudonyms without "AS" in MS Access.

So, try next

```
sSQL = "SELECT ba.BusinessEntityID,ba.AddressID
          ,IIF(ba.BusinessEntityID > 5
            ,(SELECT pp.FirstName FROM Person pp
            WHERE pp.BusinessEntityID = ba.BusinessEntityID)
            ,'AA') AS 'TEST'
    FROM BusinessEntityAddress AS ba
    INNER JOIN AddressType AS at ON at.AddressTypeID = ba.AddressTypeID
    WHERE ba.BusinessEntityID < 11;"
```

There are 2 other ways:

1) To create a VBA Function, which will be return "FirstName";

2) JOIN (left or inner, what you need) the table "Person"

Comment: thanks for the reply.. However, I get a Syntax "error in query expression IIF(ba.BusinessEntityID > 5 ,(SELECT pp.FirstName FROM [Person]![Person] pp WHERE pp.BusinessEntityID = ba.BusinessEntityID),'AA').. I cannot find any info if the IIF statement supports subqueries (which is why I came here lol). If not, can you show me an example using a Join that you had mentioned?

Comment: 1) Have you check table names? 2) Don't you forget write "AS"?  IIF(....) AS TEST ? I've checked that subqueries work in IIF

Comment: 1)Table names are good, I've been testing by checking the sSQL using debug and then pasting it in to SQL-Server (SSMS)  2) I do have AS [TEST], I've even tried AS 'Test' and 'Test' or just [TEST], still no luck...

Comment: I don't understand what you say about Sql Server, but I get the same error if I removed "AS" before field pseudonym.

Comment: Can you paste what you've used exactly? And I mean that I tested the query out in SQL Server and it works just fine.

Comment: in my database:
SELECT NW.WFIRM,
 IIF (NW.WFIRM> "006200", (SELECT FIRM_N FROM NPR_FIRMS  NF WHERE NF.FIRM_ID =  NW.WFIRM), '@@@')  AS [TST]
FROM [NPR_WORKS] AS  NW INNER  JOIN NPR_SUMS  NS ON NW.WORK_FID = NS.S_WORK_FID;
Try don't use first "[Person]!"

Answer (score 0):

When using Access, use the SWITCH function: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php

The else part is just done by saying that the condition is true.

```
sSQL = "SELECT ba.BusinessEntityID, ba.AddressID, 
         SWITCH(ba.BusinessEntityID > 5, 
        (SELECT pp.FirstName FROM [Person].[Person] 
        WHERE pp.BusinessEntityID = ba.BusinessEntityID), 
        TRUE, 'AA') AS 'TEST'
        FROM Person.BusinessEntityAddress ba
        INNER JOIN person.AddressType at ON at.AddressTypeID = ba.AddressTypeID
        WHERE ba.BusinessEntityID < 11"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. However, I get the same Syntax error as in my comment above.. "error in query expression IIF(ba.BusinessEntityID > 5 ,(SELECT pp.FirstName FROM [Person]![Person] pp WHERE pp.BusinessEntityID = ba.BusinessEntityID),'AA')

Comment: @xJustin8 -- This answer didn't have an `IIF` in it...  are you sure you copied his area9's solution?